# Left and right eigenvectors of normal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I would like to check if the following statement holds:

Claim : If a matrix is normal than it has a left eigenvector $x$ and a right eigenvector $y$ such that $x=y$

I've tried using the Spectral Theorem but I found that $x=\overline y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. The left-eigenvalue and eigenvector are conjugates of the corresponding right eval/evec. See Corr 1.7 of this set of notes: https://mosullivan.sdsu.edu/Teaching/MatrixAnalysis13s/normal.pdf